WebDriverWait with thirtyfour? (Rust Selenium)
In Selenium for Python and Java, it is possible to wait for the URL to change to a specific value. Are there similar functions in the crate thirtyfour for rust?
Java example:
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlToBe("my-url"));

Right now, I have written this wait function instead:
use tokio::time;
use tokio::time::{Duration, Instant};
use anyhow::{bail, Context, Result};
use thirtyfour::{prelude::*, Key};

async fn wait_for_url(driver: &WebDriver, url: &str, timeout: &Duration) -> Result<()> {
    let start = Instant::now();
    loop {
        time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500)).await;
        let current_url = driver.current_url().await?;
        if current_url.as_str() == url {
            return Ok(());
        }
        if &(time::Instant::now() - start) > timeout {
            bail!("Timeout waiting for {url}. Current url is {current_url}");
        }
    }
}


Did you check the docs?

@JeffC Do you have a reason to believe it's there? I couldn't find it.

@JeffC I did look at the docs, but I'm not very used to Rust and the create documentation structure yet.

I could not find a function in thirtyfour that does what you want, and what you did is essentially what the Python version does behind the hood (even with the same poll time), so I think this is what you should do.

You could something like this to replicate the behavior that you get in Python/Java.
pub trait ExpectedDriverCondition<T> {
    async fn check(&self, driver: &WebDriver) -> WebDriverResult<T>;
}

pub struct WebDriverWait<'a> {
    handle: &'a WebDriver,
    timeout: Duration,
    sleep: Duration,
}

impl<'a> WebDriverWait<'a> {
    pub fn new(
        handle: &'a WebDriver,
        timeout: Option<Duration>,
        sleep: Option<Duration>,
    ) -> WebDriverWait {
        WebDriverWait {
            handle,
            timeout: match timeout {
                Some(timeout) => timeout,
                None => BASE_TIMEOUT,
            },
            sleep: match sleep {
                Some(sleep) => sleep,
                None => BASE_SLEEP,
            },
        }
    }

    pub async fn until<T, U>(&self, ec: &T) -> WebDriverResult<U>
    where
        T: ExpectedDriverCondition<U>,
    {
        let start = Instant::now();
        loop {
            time::sleep(self.sleep).await;

            let last_error = match ec.check(self.handle).await {
                Ok(result) => break Ok(result),
                Err(error) => error,
            };

            if &(time::Instant::now() - start) > &self.timeout {
                return Err(WebDriverError::Timeout(format!(
                    "Expected condition timed out.\n{last_error}"
                )));
            }
        }
    }
}

For the base timeouts and sleep you can use:
const BASE_TIMEOUT: Duration = Duration::from_secs(5);
const BASE_SLEEP: Duration = Duration::from_millis(500);

And then you can define you ECs like this:
pub mod expected_conditions {
    use super::{ExpectedCondition, ExpectedDriverCondition, Query};
    use thirtyfour::{
        error::{WebDriverError, WebDriverResult},
        prelude::{By, WebDriver, WebElement},
    };

    pub struct UrlToBe<'a>(pub &'a String);

    impl<'a> ExpectedDriverCondition<()> for UrlToBe<'a> {
        async fn check(&self, driver: &WebDriver) -> WebDriverResult<()> {
            let current_url = driver.current_url().await?;

            if current_url.as_str() == self.0 {
                return Ok(());
            } else {
                return Err(WebDriverError::CustomError("URLs don't match".into()));
            }
        }
    }
}

To create a Wait you can do:
WebDriverWait::new(driver, Some(time::Duration::from_secs(60 * 60)), None)
            .until(&expected_conditions::UrlToBe(&self.url))
            .await?;

This way you can create more ECs as you need them.
Also, as a quick note, since WebDriver and WebElement do share common traits you'll probably have to define a WebElementWait and a WebDriverWait with different ECs for each one.
I'm pretty new to Rust, so I don't know if it's the idiomatic way to do it, but I've been using it for a project, and it's worked great so far.
Hope it helps!
